# ¿Cómo procesar la prioridad de dos métodos en dos elementos de un formulario en jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

En un formulario de cotización, tengo dos input, el primero muestra el stock de un producto, el cual se recupera de una consulta a la BD y el segundo input permite ingresar una cantidad requerida de dicho producto.

Una vez ingresada la cantidad requerida, en el método blur del input cantidad, se desarrolla la lógica para ver si el stock es suficiente para surtir la cantidad requerida.

```
$(document).on('blur', '.txtcantidad', function ()
```

Si es suficiente el stock, se sigue con los restantes pasos, si no es suficiente el stock, se envía un mensaje indicando que el stock es insuficiente para la cantidad requerida y se deja el foco puesto en el input cantidad, de modo que el usuario vuelva a ingresar una cantidad que se pueda surtir con el stock existente.

```
$row.find("td:eq(2)").find("input").focus();
```

Lo anterior impide que se siga con otras acciones sobre el formulario hasta que la cantidad requerida cumpla con ser <= que el stock, pues la lógica de validación se ejecuta cuando el input cantidad pierde el foco (blur).

Finalmente, se graba el formulario.

Posteriormente, al editar dicha cotización, el stock del artículo puede haber bajado y ahora ser menor que la cantidad requerida que se grabó, por lo tanto se va a presentar el input stock con el stock actual y el input cantidad con la cantidad cotizada, además de un mensaje que alertará esta situación Es aquí donde se me presenta una casuistica problema que no sé cómo resolverla:

Si el usuario al ver el mensaje, hace clic dentro del input cantidad y luego se arrepiente de modificar la cantidad y quiere darle clic a un botón Cancelar que cierra el formulario, NO puede hacerlo, pues al perder el foco el input cantidad, se desarrollará la lógica de validación de la cantidad requerida contra el stock, con lo cual quedo en un punto muerto.

La idea es que al hacer clic sobre el botón Cancelar, ésto tenga mayor prioridad que el blur del input cantidad, de modo que el formulario se cierre con la cotización tal como se cargó en esta instancia de EDICIÓN. Esta excepción se debe dar sólo para el botón Cancelar, pues con el otro botón existente Grabar, siempre debe grabar cotizaciones que se puedan surtir con ese stock.